# Smartgwt Listgrid Filter Issues

Tags: smartgwt

I am facing a ListGrid filter issues. The problem i am facing is when i apply any filter on the ListGrid to edit any ListGridRecord that edited records just get removed as soon as i removed filtered text from the filter of the listgrid.

When i try to get the records from the listgrid after removing filter manually as well as automatically by using listgrid.clearCriteria(). then, all my changes get removed.
Hope i am able to make sense. This is the heck i am facing for while a time. If u need to know any further detail then please let me know. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Found out the solution to this problem. actually when i remove the filtered text from the listgrid then listgrid tries to fetch the data from the server by default. by setting property setDataFetchMode(FetchMode.LOCAL) prevent the listgrid fetching the data from the server when u removed the filtered text. Thanks to all who provide assistance to me.

Answer (score 1):

About records disappearing, see this question in the SmartGWT FAQ:

http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=8159#aGrid

On clearCriteria() and changes going away, it's not clear how you're making those changes, but the changes might go away if the changes were incorrectly applied and clearCriteria() is just loading new records from the server.  See the Grid Editing Overview to understand how Records and their edits ("edit values") are stored:

http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/docs/Editing.html

Comment: Hi @Charles... one thing i would like to mention you is that when i am applying filter for the first time then only all changes going away. otherwise, applying filter for second time and consecutive times. changes didnt going away. please tell me what would the problem or give me some hint to it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

smartgwt 6 , i saw better way of doing this, you can refer the showcase

if you are using smartgwt 3 or 4 you can try the following
Grid.java:

```
    this.addFilterEditorSubmitHandler(new FilterEditorSubmitHandler(){

        @Override
        public void onFilterEditorSubmit(FilterEditorSubmitEvent event) {
             filterByEditor(event.getCriteria());

             //cancel the event to avoid the server side fetch  
             event.cancel();
        }

    });
```

DataSource.java

after fetch data, call to set the initial set of records.   zzzzzDataSrc.setCacheData(gridRecs);

---

public void filterByEditor(Criteria cr ) {

```
    AdvancedCriteria criteria =     
            new AdvancedCriteria(FLD_NM, OperatorId.STARTS_WITH, cr.getAttributeAsString(FLD_NM)) ; 
    //initialize with the complete set of rows 
    this.setData(this.getDataSource().getCacheData());
    //filter using the criteria
    this.setData(this.getDataAsRecordList().findAll(criteria)); 

}
```